# Strapi, postgres, docker: What is the right way to export a local database and export it on a remote server?

Tags: postgresql, docker, strapi

#### The problem

I have a project based on Strapi's CMS and Postgres database wrapped in docker containers which I start toghether from a single docker-compose.yml script. I have developed the project locally and want to move it on a remote server keeping the current state of all data I inserted by the CMS. In other words my local Postgres database is not empty and contains tables and information generated by the CMS. I have copied all *.js files dynamically generated from the CMS to the remote server along with the *public/* folder, but have troubles to export/import an exact copy of the database. ***What is the right way to copy the database from the docker containers?*** I prefer to export it in a single or multiple *.sql files that can be imported from the */usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh* folder.

#### What have I tried so far?

Using [*Adminer*](https://www.adminer.org/) I have exported it as a single *.sql file. It imports successfully just by placing the exported file in Postgres container's folder */usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh*. So all data I have inserted into the CMS on my local database is in the remote database. At first glance everything looks alright, until I try to update some CMS collection from the admin panel. Then in the user interface come up strange errors in the same time the Postgres and Strapi's log says this:

```
postgres         | 2023-02-17 11:44:39.438 UTC [40] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "about_pages_components_pkey"
postgres         | 2023-02-17 11:44:39.438 UTC [40] DETAIL:  Key (id)=(35) already exists.
postgres         | 2023-02-17 11:44:39.438 UTC [40] STATEMENT:  insert into "about_pages_components" ("component_id", "component_type", "entity_id", "field", "order") values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) returning "id"
api              | [2023-02-17 11:44:39.440] error: insert into "about_pages_components" ("component_id", "component_type", "entity_id", "field", "order") values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) returning "id" - duplicate key value violates unique constraint "about_pages_components_pkey"
api              | error: insert into "about_pages_components" ("component_id", "component_type", "entity_id", "field", "order") values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) returning "id" - duplicate key value violates unique constraint "about_pages_components_pkey"
api              |     at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/opt/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
api              |     at Parser.handlePacket (/opt/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
api              |     at Parser.parse (/opt/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
api              |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
api              |     at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
api              |     at Socket.emit (domain.js:475:12)
api              |     at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
api              |     at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
api              |     at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
api              |     at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
ngi
```

Adminer's export settings:

[image]

Using `docker exec -t postgres pg_dump -c -U postgres > init.sql` I get the following error log:

```
postgres         | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
postgres         | SET
postgres         | SET
postgres         | SET
postgres         | SET
postgres         | SET
postgres         |  set_config 
postgres         | ------------
postgres         |  
postgres         | (1 row)
postgres         | 
postgres         | SET
postgres         | SET
postgres         | SET
postgres         | SET
postgres         | 2023-02-17 11:50:46.045 UTC [50] ERROR:  relation "public.up_users" does not exist
postgres         | 2023-02-17 11:50:46.045 UTC [50] STATEMENT:  ALTER TABLE ONLY public.up_users DROP CONSTRAINT up_users_updated_by_id_fk;
postgres         | psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql:19: ERROR:  relation "public.up_users" does not exist
postgres         | 2023-02-17 11:50:47.358 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219) 11.2.1 20220219, 64-bit
postgres         | 2023-02-17 11:50:47.358 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres         | 2023-02-17 11:50:47.358 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres         | 2023-02-17 11:50:47.375 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres         | 2023-02-17 11:50:47.393 UTC [24] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2023-02-17 11:50:45 UTC
postgres         | 2023-02-17 11:50:51.704 UTC [24] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
postgres         | 2023-02-17 11:50:51.735 UTC [24] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/16FCE28: wanted 24, got 0
postgres         | 2023-02-17 11:50:51.735 UTC [24] LOG:  redo is not required
postgres         | 2023-02-17 11:50:52.395 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Using `docker exec -t postgres pg_dumpall -c -U postgres > init.sql` I get the following error log:

```
postgres         | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
postgres         | SET
postgres         | SET
postgres         | SET
postgres         | 2023-02-17 12:05:48.154 UTC [49] ERROR:  current user cannot be dropped
postgres         | 2023-02-17 12:05:48.154 UTC [49] STATEMENT:  DROP ROLE postgres;
postgres         | psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql:22: ERROR:  current user cannot be dropped
postgres         | 2023-02-17 12:05:49.532 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219) 11.2.1 20220219, 64-bit
postgres         | 2023-02-17 12:05:49.532 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres         | 2023-02-17 12:05:49.533 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres         | 2023-02-17 12:05:49.554 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres         | 2023-02-17 12:05:49.581 UTC [22] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2023-02-17 12:05:48 UTC
```

Strapi version and dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.2.3",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.2.3",
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.2.3",
    "better-sqlite3": "7.4.6",
    "pg": "^8.8.0"
  },
```

Postgres docker image `postgres:14.3-alpine`

Adminer docker image `adminer:4.8.1`

Comment: Just do `pg_dump` to export the database and restore it with `psql` or `pg_dump`, depending on the format used.

Comment: Well, I use pgAdmin for taking a full dump, either using `.sql` or `.backup` files. Attaching a [`docker-compose.yml`](https://github.com/CretanBull/strapi-docker) if you wish to do the same. You can easily find instructions for exporting entire db [here](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.18/backup_dialog.html)